# Can I use "in doing so at the end of sentences? Is it wrong to use the modal verb "would" in that sentence?

Tags: grammar, prepositional-phrases

"Teenagers should study all subjects at school as their knowledge would increase in doing so."

Answer (score 1):

Your example is wrong, but not for the reason you are asking about.

The phrase "in doing so" infers the consequence of an action. It can go at the end of a sentence, no problem.

But your example is hypothetical. You are saying children *should* study all subjects, and are saying what *would* happen if they did. There is not yet an action or a consequence. You could say:

> ...their knowledge would increase **by** doing so.

However, the phrase is redundant, because you are already using the conjunction 'as' to link the hypothetical action with the consequence.

Comment: Sorry, I am very confused. First, which phrase is redundant: in doing so or by doing so

Comment: Second, are you saying that "in doing so" should not be used to describe hypothetical scenarios? I thought "in doing so" just meant as a result and by is just used to describe the way one did something.

Comment: @onoseshaibu In your example, "**by** doing so" would be the correct phrase to use, for the reasons I explained in my answer. But it is redundant. We all say redundancies all the time, I would only be so critical if I was editing the written word. The phrase "**on** doing so" could be equally redundant.

Comment: Okay, I get. However, I don't see how that sentence would make sense without that phrase. Saying "Teenagers should study all subjects at school as their knowledge would increase" is not enough to convey my idea.

Comment: *The phrase "in doing so" infers the consequence of an action* - no, it **implies** the consequence of an action.  You, the reader, infer something from reading it.